# Preventing redux store value from being used again in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I learn react JavaScript and now I have a question about React Redux .

I have a component that listen to a Redux store value that is galled `newTag`

Here is the Component:

```
/*
 * Component handles creating new Tags
 */
class AddTag extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tagName: '',
            categoryName: '',
        };
    }

    submit = () => {
        const { tagName, categoryName } = this.state;
        const { tagsTag, tagsCategories } = this.props;
        // Test if the tag is already created
        const result = tagsTag.find(tag => tag.name === tagName);
        if (result) {
            if (result.category.name === categoryName.name) console.log('jj');
        }
        const { saveTag } = this.props;
        saveTag(tagName.trim(), categoryName);
    };

    changeCategoryName = categoryName => {
        this.setState({
            categoryName,
        });
    };

    changeTagName = tagName => {
        this.setState({
            tagName,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes, tagsCategories, isSavingNewTagStarted, newTagErrMsg, newTag } = this.props;
        const { tagName, categoryName } = this.state;

        return (
            <Container className={classes.root}>
                <Typography className={classes.typography} gutterBottom variant="h6" align="left">
                    Type the new Tag name and select the Tag category
                </Typography>
                <div>
                    <TextField
                        className={classes.tagTextField}
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        label="New Tag Name"
                        placeholder="New Tag Name"
                        variant="outlined"
                        value={tagName}
                        onChange={e => this.changeTagName(e.target.value)}
                        autoComplete="off"
                        InputProps={{
                            className: classes.inputBackground,
                        }}
                        InputLabelProps={{
                            className: classes.inputLabel,
                        }}
                    />
                    <FormControl>
                        <InputLabel id="category-select">Category</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            className={classes.selectInput}
                            labelId="category-select"
                            id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                            value={categoryName}
                            onChange={e => this.changeCategoryName(e.target.value)}
                        >
                            {tagsCategories &&
                                tagsCategories.map((element, index) => {
                                    return element.name !== 'All Tags' ? (
                                        <MenuItem value={element} key={element.id}>
                                            {element.name}
                                        </MenuItem>
                                    ) : null;
                                })}
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                    <Button
                        className={classes.button}
                        onClick={() => this.submit()}
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        disabled={!tagName || !categoryName}
                    >
                        Save Tag
                    </Button>
                    {newTagErrMsg && <p className="error">{newTagErrMsg.message}</p>}
                    {newTag && <p>New Tag was saved!</p>}
                </div>
                <div>{isSavingNewTagStarted ? <Dots /> : null}</div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    saveTag: (name, category) => dispatch(saveNewTag(name, category)),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        tagsCategories: state.global.tagsCategories,
        tagsTag: state.global.tags,
        isSavingNewTagStarted: state.global.isSavingNewTagStarted,
        newTagErrMsg: state.global.newTagErrMsg,
        newTag: state.global.newTag,
    };
};
const enhance = compose(withStyles(styles), connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps));
export default enhance(AddTag);
```

When a new Tag is saved this code line is true:

```
    {newTag && <p>New Tag was saved!</p>}
```

problem is that the `newTag` from Redux store is after the new tag is saved, always true.
So this means that the text "New Tag was saved" is then always visible.

I wonder about a way to reset the Redux store `newTag` so the text "New Tag was saved" is not showed after some render later.

- should I dispatch a call to the store and setting `newTag` like 'nothing' (it is not used anywhere else)
- should I create some `localstorage` variable to use and test for if `newTag` is same as before then the "New Tag was saved" will not be showed.

Is there some Redux way method I have missed maybe?

Here is the reduces following well known praxis I think.

```
import { globalActionTypes } from './global.types';

const INIT_STATE = {
    tags: [],
    tagsCategories: [],

    isSavingNewTagStarted: false,
    newTag: '',
    newTagErrMsg: '',
};

const globalReducer = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // SET_TAGS_ADDED
        case globalActionTypes.SET_TAGS:
            return {
                ...state,
                tags: action.payload,
            };
        // SET_TAGS_CATEGORIES
        case globalActionTypes.SET_TAGS_CATEGORIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                tagsCategories: action.payload,
            };
        // ADD_NEW_TAG
        case globalActionTypes.ADD_NEW_TAG_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                isSavingNewTagStarted: true,
            };
        case globalActionTypes.ADD_NEW_TAG_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isSavingNewTagStarted: false,
                newTag: action.payload,
            };
        case globalActionTypes.ADD_NEW_TAG_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isSavingNewTagStarted: false,
                newTagErrMsg: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default globalReducer;
```

Comment: Can you use `setTimeout` to make the message disappear?

Comment: @Evert setting `setTimeout` would work but it feels like bad praxis regarding the lifecycle of redux store variables, should I when timeout fire then `dispatch` to the store and make `newTag` = nothing, yea maybe it's a good way

Comment: Personally I believe that redux events should deal with describing application state, but perhaps not the presentation of that state. But I understand that that line can get blurry.

Comment: I don't think you should rely on `newTag` being truthy to render that message. Only render that `<p/>` whenever your tag is actually saved. You can also just use the local state for a flag when rendering that text.

Comment: @GregKonush Not sure I follow you, when the tag is saved the Redux store `newTag` is set. The only way to know in the Component when `newTag`  is set, is to `mapStateToProp  for `newTag`. Maybe you can create an Answer explaining?

Comment: @GregKonush local state is wiped on refresh so the only way to know if `newTag` was set is to listen for Redux state change

Answer (score 4):

Just dispatch an action to clear `newTag`. No need to ruminate over it.

Comment: But I want to know more ways, options, and also bad ways. I want to learn.
Yeas your answer is the best so far ya

Comment: Good for you but remember that your time isn't infinite. Instead of mulling over this simple case go build something complex. I'd be much better investment of your time.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App) is a privat project with no deadline :) :) so I got time really thanks. Please [join](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App) to help out!

Answer (score 1):

As of good practices, will not recommend changing the redux store for the manipulation of UI of the app. Redux should store data to be displayed.

Solution for the above case can be done in the following way:

1. Define a new state variable "tagStatus" in the component, which will be set once the new tag is added.
2. However, timeout here will also be added having a handler that will reset the "tagStatus".

In this way, we are not changing anything in redux and are also able to solve the issue by changing the code on the component level.

Answer (score -2):

try to pass `...state` to the default case

```
default:
  return {
    ...state
  }
```

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @JakubMichálek I am not shore about this but I got my state back when I update the state and the updated state create a new child of the previous state and by spreading the default state I solve my issue.